# OPENQUERY(SERVERNAME, STOREDPROCEDURE) Syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, openquery

This is my code

```
DECLARE @stringvariable nvarchar(200) = 'Hello';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(2000) = SELECT * INTO ##global FROM OPENQUERY(DB1, ''EXEC GETCASE ''' + @stringvariable + ''''')'
```

Printing `@sql` returns a correctly formatted query, however SQL Server doesn't like `@stringvariable` and returns an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near 'Hello'.

Here is what the outputted query looks like

```
SELECT * INTO ##global FROM OPENQUERY(DB1, 'EXEC GETCASE 'Hello'')
```

How can I avoid this error? It seems like because my stored procedure takes a string parameter, it's throwing off the query. I've read that `OPENQUERY` does not support variables, but I've parameter the variable so it should work?

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Microsoft article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/sql/admin/pass-variable-linked-server-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stored procedure exists in a database and a schema. You need to supply those. Supposing database `db_name` and schema `schema_name`:

```
DECLARE @stringvariable nvarchar(200) = 'Hello';
SET @stringvariable=REPLACE(@stringvariable,'''',''''''''''); -- doubly doubled single quotes for the dynamic statement
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(2000) = 'SELECT * INTO ##global FROM OPENQUERY(DB1, ''SET FMTONLY OFF;EXEC db_name.schema_name.GETCASE ''''' + @stringvariable + ''''''')';
```

I've also made sure single quotes are properly escaped in the `@stringvariable`.

It's also likely you need to start the query with `SET FMTONLY OFF;` so I've added that.

---

Update: To test this I created following simple procedure on a linked server `local_server` in database `TEST_TT`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[tst]
    @i VARCHAR(128)
AS
    SELECT @i AS field;
```

I then ran the following:

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(128)='TT.';
SET @var=REPLACE(@var,'''',''''''''''); -- doubly doubled single quotes for the dynamic statement
DECLARE @stmt VARCHAR(4000)='SELECT * INTO ##tt FROM OPENQUERY(local_server,''SET FMTONLY OFF;EXEC TEST_TT.dbo.tst '''''+@var+''''''');';
EXEC (@stmt);
SELECT * FROM ##tt;
DROP TABLE ##tt;
```

And I received the results. I count 7 (!!) single quotes at the end of the query... yuck! Updated original part with the same number of quotes.

Comment: Hi TT thanks for your response, I am using the dbname, and schema name but I didn't add that in my Stackoverflow code. I followed your format but I am still getting the same error. The output that is printed out is the same as before (except that it now displays 'SET FMTONLY OFF;')

Comment: @GovindRai Updated with something that works on my system (2012).

Comment: @GovindRai one more change in replacing the single quotes in the variable. Dynamic SQL can get ugly =)

Comment: Hi TT. Thanks for your updates! I guess I did get one step further with your answer but now I get a `THE OLDE DB provider "SQLNCLT11" for linked server "XXXXX" supplied inconsisent metadate for a column. The column "COLUMX" was reported to have a "Incomplete schema-error logic"

Comment: Also could you explain what exactly the doubly doubled single quotes replacement does? I can't figure out the logic behind that.

Comment: @GovindRai To have strings in a dynamic query, you need to double quotes in in them. In this case since the string appears within a string in a dynamic statement, you need to do that twice (ie doubly doubled). Just try the test sp + call that I posted without doubling the quotes (twice), you will see that it wil fail.

Comment: @GovindRai As to the comment before that: the problem you asked about in the question is solved. I'll happily accept the ✔ =). If you can't find a solution to the other problem, you will need to ask a new question detailing the stored procedure etc. One question per question, otherwise it gets too chaotic.

Comment: Understood. Thank you

Comment: Not sure, why you added SET FMTONLY OFF; it should be off by default. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-fmtonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim A long time ago (more than 10 years at least) I've had a case where that was required. I don't recall the circumstances anymore. Perhaps it's not particularly needed as I stated.