# Passing variable in OPENQUERY for a linked server name

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

How can I pass `Linked server` name as a variable?

something like this:

```
declare @A varchar(55) = 'LinkedServerName'

select * from OPENQUERY(@A,'select 1')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OPENQUERY(SERVERNAME, STOREDPROCEDURE) Syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565067/openqueryservername-storedprocedure-syntax-error)

Answer (score 1):

This helped. Here I have to create variable for the whole `openquery`, and than excute it by dynamic SQL.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314520